Register program to Windows share menu
Windows 10 introduced a new share menu, which can be accessed, among other ways, by right-clicking a file in the File Explorer and choosing "Share".

I'm developing a Windows program and I'd like to register it to appear in this system share menu. I've found this example that specifies the share capabilities in AppxManifest.xml. However, I'm using Avalonia as my UI framework, not UWP.
What do I need to configure in order to use an AppxManifest.xml file in an Avalonia C# Project?
Answers that don't require code signing are preferred, because I don't want to purchase a digital certificate. (The program is open-source and developed in my free time).

Solution 1:
According to this question  on Stack Overflow, "ShareTaget" is probably possible using the "Desktop Bridge Platform" for all Windows desktop applications, but I did not test this method myself.
Note:
The current question is not a duplicate of the one mentioned, as it is described in WPF, but is discussed here in Avalonia.

Solution 2:
You can create a UWP application that is "ShareTarget" and after receiving the content, save it in a temporary file and close the UWP app, and then another application, for example your Avalonia app, using "FileSystemWatcher" or any other useful and possible mechanism, display the file.
Note:
Of course, instead of monitoring the file, if you can do the file access settings for UWP, maybe you can run a secondary program, for example, your own program with the command line parameter from within UWP, which I do not recommend even if it is possible. Because if it is distributed in the "Microsoft Store", maybe these accesses cause problems. It's also not easy to run the app from within UWP, see here for more details.
According to Microsoft documentation, we create a UWP Shared Target for the text file as a sample:

1- Enable "Developer Mode" in "Windows Settings":
To do this, search for the word "Developer" in "Settings" and activate "Developer
Mode" in the "Use Developer Features" section.
2- In "Visual Studio 2022", create a "Blank APP (Universal Windows)"
project.
3- Modify "Package.appxmanifest" by double clicking on the file
and select and add "Share Target" in the "Declarations" tab. Then
create an item in "Data formats" with the "Add New" button and type
"Text", then add an item below it in the "Supported file types"
section with the "Add New" button and type ".txt" and remove the
"ExecutableOrStartPageIsRequired" tick and save the changes.
4- Add the following code to the "App.xaml" file.
5- Run the program to build and deploy. This will also install our app package for the current user to be able to send a text file to "share" (share text content).

App.xaml:
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var sharedText = "Shared Text:" + Environment.NewLine;
    ShareOperation shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;
    if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        sharedText += await shareOperation.Data.GetTextAsync();
    WriteTempFileAndGetFullFilePath("SharedText.txt", sharedText);
    await Task.Delay(2500);
    Current.Exit();
}
private string WriteTempFileAndGetFullFilePath(string FileName, string Text, bool ReleaseFileAccessAfterWriting = true)
{
    var TempFolder = Path.GetTempPath();
    var FullFilePath = Path.Combine(TempFolder, FileName);
    if (ReleaseFileAccessAfterWriting)
    {
        if (File.Exists(FullFilePath))
            File.Delete(FullFilePath);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FullFilePath))
            writer.Write(Text);
    }
    else
        File.WriteAllText(FullFilePath, Text);
    return FullFilePath;
}

Now we create a "Windows Forms App" for .NET 6.0 or later that monitors the temporary file. This program should be set to run automatically at startup.
Note:
In the final program that will be installed on the computer, instead of the "TEXT_FILE_PATH" constant string, you should put the path of the temporary file in the package installed for UWP.
Program.cs:
namespace TextViewer
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(params string[] args)
        {
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Form1.SetTextFilePath(args);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

Form1.cs:
namespace TextViewer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Width = 600;
            Height = 400;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            Text = "TextViewer";
        }
        private TextBox textBoxMain = new();
        private FileSystemWatcher? watcher = null;
        public const string TEXT_FILE_PATH = @"C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Packages\65677ffggb_gggfgdx\Temp\SharedText.txt";
        public static string TextFilePath { get; private set; } = "";
        public static void SetTextFilePath(string[] args)
        {
            if ((args.Length > 0) && args[0].ToLower().EndsWith(".txt"))
                TextFilePath = args[0];
        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            textBoxMain = CreateTextBox();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextFilePath))
                TextFilePath = TEXT_FILE_PATH;
            AddFileWatcher(TextFilePath);
        }
        private void ShowTextFile(TextBox textBox, string TextFilePath)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextFilePath))
                try
                {
                    textBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(TextFilePath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ShowError(ex);
                }
        }
        private void ShowError(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        private void AddFileWatcher(string FullFilePath)
        {
            string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(FullFilePath) ?? "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPath))
            {
                if (watcher != null)
                {
                    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                    watcher.Dispose();
                }
                watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
                {
                    Path = folderPath,
                    Filter = "*.txt",
                    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size
                };
                watcher.Created += Watcher_CreatedOrChanged;
                watcher.Changed += Watcher_CreatedOrChanged;
                watcher.Error += Watcher_Error;
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
        }
        private void Watcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => ShowError(e.GetException())));
            AddFileWatcher(TextFilePath);
        }
        private void OpenFile(FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            var FullFilePath = e.FullPath;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullFilePath) && FullFilePath.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt"))
                ShowTextFile(textBoxMain, FullFilePath);
        }
        private void Watcher_CreatedOrChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Invoke(new Action(() => OpenFile(e)));         
        }
        private TextBox CreateTextBox()
        {
            var textBoxMain = new TextBox
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Location = new Point(0, 0),
                Multiline = true,
                Name = "textBoxMain",
                ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both,
                TabIndex = 0
            };
            Controls.Add(textBoxMain);
            return textBoxMain;
        }
    }
}


Solution #2 is unacceptable, since I don't want to purchase a digital certificate (and the end users wouldn't have developer mode enabled).
Can you expand on solution #1? How do I define an AppxManifest.xml in an Avalonia project?

I've done a bit of reading and it looks like the sharing API, along with several other new Windows APIs, inherently require a packaged (non-portable) app. Specifically, a signed one. This sucks but there's no way around it. Guess I won't be using these new features

@Bip901, I have to say:

I did not say anywhere in my solution that a digital certificate is necessary.
I think that your customers don't need to enable Developer Mode. This option is required for UWP application development in Visual Studio, and after debugging and package installation, you can turn off this option. Microsoft says here "the Developer Mode setting enables debugging and additional deployment options."


@Bip901, 3) "ShareTarget" can be used for Windows 10 and 11 applications. UWP is also designed for Windows only, but as far as I know, the important reason for using Avalonia is to create a cross-platform UI. I didn't understand exactly why you use Avalonia?

but in any case, it can be said that the Stack Overflow question mentioned in my solution 1 is also based on the adding UWP features to your project, as mentioned in this link, you can change the manifest file But then you need to add UWP features to the project.


In the question, you said "Answers that don't require code signing are preferred", you didn't say it is required. In any case, I think my second solution doesn't require code signing unless you want to distribute on the Microsoft Store, which might be necessary, I don't know.



Apparently, this feature of "ShareTarget" requires the use of UWP-based packaging tools, which if you are planning to build a cross-platform application, considering that this feature does not add much to the value of your product, it is better to ignore it as you said, unless someone else writes a better solution under the question.


@Bip901, In any case, I tried to write the most complete answer that I could find according to your needs. If I come up with a better solution, I will let you know.

If we want to give a short answer to the question "What do I need to configure in order to use an AppxManifest.xml file in an Avalonia C# Project?" In my opinion, we can say:
"Changing the AppxManifest.xml file based on the mentioned links and adding UWP features to your project or creating a UWP package and interacting with that UWP application", these solutions may not be easy.
